# How to access environment variables from .properties using java?

Tags: java, environment-variables, amazon-sqs, application.properties

I'm using java to implement AWS SQS. I want to have a .properties file in which I want to store and access an environment variable for an AWS SQS Access and Secret Key. At the moment, my .properties file is:

```
dev.access.key={$AWS_ACCESS_KEY}
dev.secret.access.key={$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
```

My code to access these variables is:

```
String awsAccessKey = properties.getProperty("dev.access.key");
String awsSecretAccessKey = properties.getProperty("dev.secret.access.key");
```

I have already instantiated properties and it's well defined. I'm able to get other properties but unable to access the environment variables Access and Secret Key, which I require. That is currently awsAccessKey, awsSecretAccessKey are defined as null. Is there perhaps something wrong with my syntax of how I'm accessing those environment variables?

Comment: Can you read other properties from the same file?

Comment: Can you print out all the properties?

Comment: I can read other properties and I get all the correct values when I print them all out. That said all the other properties are Strings. There are the only two that are environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with https://github.com/webcompere/lightweight-config

Your placeholder syntax would need to change slightly:

```
dev.access.key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}
dev.secret.access.key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
```

Then you'd write:

```java
Properties myProps = ConfigLoader.loadPropertiesFromResource(
    myproperties.properties");
```

Lightweight Config also supports properties on filesystem, rather than on the classpath (as above) and allows you to use YML instead of the `.properties` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html)

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor;

public class EnvSubst {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // For the demo, create a Properties, normally you will read Properties from file
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("tempfolder", "${TEMP}");

        System.out.println("path value : " + 
            new StringSubstitutor(System.getenv()).replace(p.get("tempfolder")));
    }
}
```